# Error when using command setup:di:compile .Sm/CartQuickPro

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, theme, third-party-module, setup-di-compile

```
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 70.0 MiB
Fatal error: Interface 'Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/Sm/CartQuickPro/Controller/Product/Compare/Remove.php on line 19
```

and use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
 is used 3 times in module . I have magento2.2.4 and I am using https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ3TW.png marked one but it countains

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
```

I think it's exactly the same as it is in 2.3.4 folder. 
what can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `HttpPostActionInterface.php` is not available in Magento 2.2.* . It was only introduced in Magento 2.3.* .

Check the URL in the images:

[image: Magento 2.2.*]

[image: Magento 2.3.*]

To be precise it was added on 31 Jul 2018 and was intended for Magento 2.3 release.

Comment: Yes thats true ! they sent module for  2.2.x as well but they were still using thathttppostactioninterface ... kind a shitcode is that sm cartquickpro. now trying to install infortis theme but have composer problem, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310692/can-not-install-module-with-artifacts take a look if any suggestion thank you