# can not install module with artifacts

Tags: magento2, module, composer, third-party-module

I am trying to install new module using artifacts and composer. It returns an error at the end

```
> ([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/)

Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Module 'Infortis_UltraSlideshow' from '/var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/UltraSlideshow' has been already defined in '/var/www/html/vendor/Infortis/UltraSlideshow'. in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Component/ComponentRegistrar.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/Infortis/UltraSlideshow/registration.php(6): Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register('module', 'Infortis_UltraS...', '/var/www/html/a...')
#1 /var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): require_once('/var/www/html/a...')
#2 [internal function]: Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}('/var/www/html/a...')
#3 /var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(33): Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(70): require('/var/www/html/a...')
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(60): c in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Component/ComponentRegistrar.php on line 50
Script ([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/) handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

it reverts changes from composer.json but under app/code(I dont know why there) and in vendor module is installed. 
tried that https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core/issues/3 but no success.

Comment: you what want to result.i don't understand please explain shortly

Comment: @MohitPatel It fails in the end and I must push composer.json and composer.lock at the end but it reverts .... I just want to install 3rd party module using artifact.

Comment: I think there is a problem with namespace. It seems that there is already another class named UltraSlideShow, which is available in the vendor folder by the same vendor(Infotrils). So Instead of using it via app/code, try using the file in the vendor folder.